# Создание таблицы с помощью паттерна mvvm. Таблица не обновляется

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Недавно я начал изучать технологию WPF. Столкнулся с одной проблемой. Создал таблицу работники и отдел. но таблица не обновляется, помогите пожалуйста.
Вот код:

***ContactManagerViewModel.cs***

```
public class ContactManagerViewModel: ObservableCollection<Contacts>
{
    public ContactManagerViewModel()
    {
        PrepareContactCollection();
    }

    private void PrepareContactCollection()
    {
        var contactOne = new Contacts
        {
            ID="1",
            FirstName = "Исмоил",
            LastName = "Мухаммадиев",
            Professional = "Программист"
        };
        Add(contactOne);

        var contactTwo = new Contacts
        {
            ID = "2",
            FirstName = "Жавлонбой",
            LastName = "Обидов",
            Professional = "Дизайнер"
        };
        Add(contactTwo);

        var contactThree = new Contacts
        {
            ID = "3",
            FirstName = "Анвар",
            LastName = "Еркинов",
            Professional = "Веб Программист"
        };
        Add(contactThree);

        var contactFour = new Contacts
        {
            ID = "4",
            FirstName = "Наталья",
            LastName = "Ким",
            Professional = "Дизайнер"
        };
        Add(contactFour);

        var contact5 = new Contacts
        {
            ID = "5",
            FirstName = "Фаррух",
            LastName = "Исматов",
            Professional = "3д аниматор"
        };
        Add(contact5);
    }
}
```

***Contacts.cs***

```
public class Contacts : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string id;
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string professional;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public string Professional
    {
        get { return professional; }
        set
        {
            professional = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Professional");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModel:ContactManagerViewModel x:Key="contactViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="93*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="27*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BorderThickness="2" x:Name="lstContacts"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=contactViewModel}"
              DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" Margin="0,0,-131,-91" Grid.RowSpan="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="ID"  />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="FirstName" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="LastName" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="Professional"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Path=Professional}"/>
</Grid>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new ContactManagerViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Если вы не запостите код, мы вряд ли сможем понять, где именно ошибка. [mcve]

Comment: Окей, это уже лучше. В коде вроде пока проблем не видно. А что означает «не обновляется»? Что вы делаете, что происходит при этом, и чего вы ожидаете?

Comment: Когда я выбираю другого сотрудника его данные не показывает

Comment: Так, а данные самого первого сотрудника показывает?

Comment: самого первого сотрудника показывает

Comment: Ага, это уже интересно. Сейчас подумаю.

Comment: А где вы устанавливаете `DataContext`?

Comment: DanaContext не устанавливаю

Comment: Странно, а как же тогда данные попадают в `{Binding Path=ID}`?

Comment: А что происходит в `MainWindow_Loaded`? Может быть, там что-то интересное?

Comment: Давайте вы свой эмайл напишите я вам эту программу отправлю

Comment: Не, простите, если я опубликую email, мне будет писать слишком много людей. Давайте вы всё же выложите код `MainWindow_Loaded`, так будет проще. (Видите ссылку «править» под вопросом?)

Comment: private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new ContactManagerViewModel();
        }

Comment: О, а вы говорите, что не устанавливаете `DataContext` :) Тогда всё понятно, сейчас напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас присутствует два экземпляра `ContactManagerViewModel`: один у вас объявлен в ресурсах, и к нему привязывается `ListView`, а другой устанавливается в качестве `DataContext`, и к нему привязываются `TextBox`'ы.

Уберите один из них.

Например, я убрал бы `ContactManagerViewModel` из ресурсов, и написал так:

```
<ListView ...
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" .../>
```

Кстати, я бы оформил `Binding` как `Text="{Binding Path=/ID}"`, со слешем, т. к. вы всё же привязываетесь к текущему элементу. Но судя по всему работает и так.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Благодарю вас. Получилось)))

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев в таком случае принято отмечать ответ зеленой галочкой.

Comment: Ок. Буду теперь знать

Comment: Хотел ещё спросить. Как можно использовать ObservableCollection. Чтоб  все данные в одном месте были

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев: Не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос, вы ведь и так используете `ObservableCollection` в вашем коде?

Comment: Все правильно, я просто забыл что я использую observabCollection